# How to define Generic Types in a specialized interface using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate model project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, generics, interface, code-generation

I have defined an interface `IFoo<T, U>` in a package. In a separate package I want to define an interface as ISpecialFoo which will implement `IFoo<T, U> where T: string, U: int`.

However, when I create the ISpecialFoo interface on the diagram, and add the relationship to IFoo, I can not get the T and U to be in the generated code without defining ISpecialFoo as `ISpecialFoo<string, int>` - which is precisely what I don't want to do.

Does anyone know a way to set the Template Binding or Template Parameters on ISpecialFoo so that it generates the code file appropriately?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you really want to declare is:

```
interface ISpecialFoo : IFoo<string, int>
```

That way `ISpecialFoo` is no longer generic itself - it is deriving from `IFoo<T, U>` and evaluating `T` and `U` to `string` and `int` respectively.

As to how you specify this with your modeling thingamajig, I can't say.

Comment: That is exactly what I want to have declared, but VS2010 doesn't seem to support modelling interfaces in this manner. I'm hoping someone out here has figured out a way to deal with this without modifying the generated code.